# EXTJS 4 render HTML of a selected value in a combobox

Tags: html, extjs, combobox, extjs4

Hello I have the next problem, I want to render the html of my display value in a combobox, at the moment I load a store with the html ready, it renders the html when I show all of them, but when I select one, it show the html.

What can I do to render the html when the item is already selected?

Here are some images to help to explain the inconvenient:

**This is when Im going to select one**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcfRA.jpg

**This is when I select one**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzi9r.jpg

The Html that I'm rendering is the next one:

```
<img class="io_img" src="/files/images/io-P.gif"/><div class="io_desc">hola</div></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

PD: Sorry to no show the images, and just the links, but I don't have enough reputation to show images directly .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This require few steps. Problem is that `ComboBox` has input field underneath, and inputs can't display html. So first step is to change template which replace input with div. Eg:

```
fieldSubTpl: [
    '<div class="{hiddenDataCls}" role="presentation"></div>',
    '<div id="{id}" type="{type}" ',
        '<tpl if="size">size="{size}" </tpl>',
        '<tpl if="tabIdx">tabIndex="{tabIdx}" </tpl>',
        'class="{fieldCls} {typeCls}" autocomplete="off"></div>',
    '<div id="{cmpId}-triggerWrap" class="{triggerWrapCls}" role="presentation">',
        '{triggerEl}',
        '<div class="{clearCls}" role="presentation"></div>',
    '</div>',
    {
        compiled: true,
        disableFormats: true
    }
]
```

Then change template which shows selected value:

```
displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', [ 
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<img src="http://phpbb3.pl/adm/images/icon_edit.gif" />',
    '{[typeof values === "string" ? values : values["title"]]}',
    '</tpl>'
])
```

Another thing is to create new list-item template. Eg:

```
listConfig: {
    getInnerTpl: function() {
        return '<div class="search-item">' +
            '<h3><img src="http://phpbb3.pl/adm/images/icon_edit.gif" /><span>{[Ext.Date.format(values.lastPost, "M j, Y")]}<br />by {author}</span>{title}</h3>' +
            '{excerpt}' +
        '</div>';
    }
}
```

And the last thing - you must ensure that the value is set correctly into div. For that you should override `setRawValue` method:

```
setRawValue: function(value) {
    var me = this;
    value = Ext.value(value, '');
    me.rawValue = value;

    // Some Field subclasses may not render an inputEl
    if (me.inputEl) {
        // me.inputEl.dom.value = value;
        // use innerHTML
        me.inputEl.dom.innerHTML = value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Notice that new template doesn't contain any `input` field, so value will not be submited. If you need use such combo with form, you should add hidden input somewhere in `fieldSubTpl` and set value for it in `setRawValue`.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/8Xs5h/1/

Comment: OMG!, its quite a lot of stuff to do, I just want to ask you how can I manage the html I get from the server, because the displayField is receiving an html directly, not a text, then if you can guide me what's the better approach in this case. thanks.

Comment: in IE extjs is unable to register "click" event to the fieldSubTpl. addEventListener is undefined

Comment: Fix: remove the triggerwrap -> '<div id="{cmpId}-triggerWrap" class="{triggerWrapCls}" role="presentation">',
        '{triggerEl}',
        '<div class="{clearCls}" role="presentation"></div>',
    '</div>',

Also works in IE & Firefox then

Comment: @ferchotipin How you did with dynamic html from server?

Comment: @Krzysztof have you checkd it with extJs6? I tried to but it's not worked as I thought it would

Comment: @Krzysztof tried yesterday but maybe I do smth wrong or now it interpretate `displayTpl` different way 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34946014/combobox-showing-html-as-text

Comment: @Krzysztof great example of doing things the right way. Trying to do this as a multi-select. Will post back, but if you know please update your answer. Thx

Answer (score 0):

We have similar task to display selected color. Our solution is overriding of combobox template:

```
var store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
    fields: ['num','id', 'color']
});

var tplColor = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for="."><div id = "seriesColor_{num}" class="combo-result-item">',
       '<div  class="combo-texture" style="background-color:{color};">&nbsp;</div>',
    '</div></tpl>'
 );

new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    tpl: tplColor,
    store: store,
    ...
};
```

You can do something similar but use image instead of background-color.