# ComboBox showing HTML as text

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs6

My `treecolumn` has a ComboBox as the editor component. The choices in the options menu are rendered correctly with HTML, but the input box does not render HTML, it only shows the tags (See images below.)

How I can make it to also render the value as HTML?

P.S.
This solution here [EXTJS 4 render HTML of a selected value in a combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016859/extjs-4-render-html-of-a-selected-value-in-a-combobox) is seems like not working with extjs6 version, check [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14g9)

[image: First step]

[image: Second step]

Here's the problem place code (rendere in case `depth.TypeParameter:` returns text with html tags)

```
 {
                    xtype: 'treecolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'text',
                    text: Poly.utils.locale.Base.localeName,
                    flex: 1,
                    getEditor: function (record) {
                        return me.getController().getEditor(record);
                    },
                    renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
                        var depth = Poly.view.fluidProperties.sample.Tree.depth;
                        switch (record.getDepth()) {
                            case depth.Temperature:
                                if (Ext.isEmpty(record.get('temperature'))) {
                                    return value;
                                }
                                var text = Ext.String.format('T = {0} {1}',
                                    record.get('temperature').toFixed(2),
                                    Poly.utils.UniSum.GetUnit(me.getViewModel().get('temperatureUnitId')).name);

                                return text;
                            case depth.TypeParameter:
                                if (record.get('isNew')) {
                                    return value;
                                }
                                return Poly.enums.TypeFluidParameter.getName(record.get('fluidParameter'), record.parentNode.get('typeFluid'), true);
                        }
                        return value;
                    }
                }
```

Full code here

```
    Ext.define('Poly.view.fluidProperties.sample.Tree', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',

    xtype: 'fluidPropertiesSampleTree',

    viewModel: {
        type: 'fluidPropertiesSampleTreeViewModel'
    },

    controller: 'fluidPropertiesSampleTreeController',

    statics: {
        /** Уровень элемента в дереве */
        depth: {
            /** Корень */
            Root: 0,
            /** Замер */
            Sample: 1,
            /** Тип среды */
            TypeFluid: 2,
            /** Параметер */
            TypeParameter: 3,
            /** Температура */
            Temperature: 4
        }
    },

    lines: false,
    rootVisible: false,
    useArrows: true,
    enableColumnHide: false,
    enableColumnResize: false,
    sortableColumns: false,

    border: true,

    viewConfig: {
        cls: 'gridActionColumnHide'
    },

    dockedItems: [
        {
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            ui: 'footer',
            cls: 'transparent',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'middle',
                pack: 'center'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    cls: 'pvt-chart-button',
                    text: '', // локализация в initComponent
                    flex: 2,
                    name: 'addSample',
                    margin: 2
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    cls: 'pvt-chart-button',
                    text: '', // локализация в initComponent
                    flex: 1,
                    name: 'import',
                    disabled: true,
                    margin: 2
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    cls: 'pvt-chart-button',
                    text: '', // локализация в initComponent
                    flex: 1,
                    name: 'export',
                    disabled: true,
                    margin: 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ],

    listeners: {
        checkchange: 'nodeCheckChange',
        edit: 'edit'
    },
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 2
    },

    bind: {
        selection: '{selectedRecord}'
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this,
            store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                root: {
                    expanded: true,
                    children: []
                }
            }),
            controller = me.getController();

        me.dockedItems[0].items[0].text = me.locale.addSample;
        me.dockedItems[0].items[1].text = me.locale.importText;
        me.dockedItems[0].items[2].text = me.locale.exportText;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            store: store,
            columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'treecolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'text',
                    text: Poly.utils.locale.Base.localeName,
                    flex: 1,
                    getEditor: function (record) {
                        return me.getController().getEditor(record);
                    },
                    renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
                        var depth = Poly.view.fluidProperties.sample.Tree.depth;
                        switch (record.getDepth()) {
                            case depth.Temperature:
                                if (Ext.isEmpty(record.get('temperature'))) {
                                    return value;
                                }
                                var text = Ext.String.format('T = {0} {1}',
                                    record.get('temperature').toFixed(2),
                                    Poly.utils.UniSum.GetUnit(me.getViewModel().get('temperatureUnitId')).name);

                                return text;
                            case depth.TypeParameter:
                                if (record.get('isNew')) {
                                    return value;
                                }
                                return Poly.enums.TypeFluidParameter.getName(record.get('fluidParameter'), record.parentNode.get('typeFluid'), true);
                        }
                        return value;
                    }
                },
                {
                    width: 30,
                    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                    name: 'menuWidgetcolumn',
                    widget: {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        margin: '5 0 0 0',
                        arrowCls: '',
                        width: 15,
                        height: 15,
                        style: {
                            'background-color': '000000',
                            'border-color': '000000'
                        },
                        menu: {
                            xtype: 'colormenu',
                            listeners: {
                                select: function (component, color) {
                                    var button = component.up('button');

                                    button.setStyle('background-color', color);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    onWidgetAttach: function (column, widget, record) {
                        widget.setVisible(Ext.isNumber(record.get('temperature')));
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    width: 25,
                    items: [
                        {
                            handler: 'removeTreeItem',
                            getClass: function (v, meta, rec) {
                                if (!rec.get('isNew')) {
                                    return 'poly-trash-icon';
                                }
                                return '';
                            },
                            getTip: function (v, meta, rec) {
                                if (!rec.get('isNew')) {
                                    return 'Delete';
                                }
                                return '';
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });

        me.getSampleNode = controller.getSampleNode;
        me.setTypeMode = Ext.bind(controller.setTypeMode, controller);

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't, text fields don't render html.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli hmm, maybe I can put `button` inside? could that work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXTJS 4 render HTML of a selected value in a combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016859/extjs-4-render-html-of-a-selected-value-in-a-combobox)

Comment: @Tyr hmm, thank you, my first attempt (just copypasted code) wasn't succesful but well, I got some info now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html input element can't display HTML, so you need to change template add div. Div can be shown as an overlay over input.

Best way to achieve this is by extending ComboBox:

```
    Ext.define('HtmlComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
    fieldSubTpl: [ // note: {id} here is really {inputId}, but {cmpId} is available
        '<input id="{id}" data-ref="inputEl" type="{type}" {inputAttrTpl}',
            ' size="1"', // allows inputs to fully respect CSS widths across all browsers
            '<tpl if="name"> name="{name}"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="value"> value="{[Ext.util.Format.htmlEncode(values.value)]}"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="placeholder"> placeholder="{placeholder}"</tpl>',
            '{%if (values.maxLength !== undefined){%} maxlength="{maxLength}"{%}%}',
            '<tpl if="readOnly"> readonly="readonly"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="disabled"> disabled="disabled"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="tabIdx != null"> tabindex="{tabIdx}"</tpl>',
            '<tpl if="fieldStyle"> style="{fieldStyle}"</tpl>',
            '<tpl foreach="inputElAriaAttributes"> {$}="{.}"</tpl>',
        ' class="{fieldCls} {typeCls} {typeCls}-{ui} {editableCls} {inputCls}" autocomplete="off"/>',
        // overlay element to show formatted value
        '<div id="{cmpId}-overlayEl" data-ref="overlayEl"<tpl if="name"> name="{name}-overlayEl"</tpl> class="{fieldCls}-overlay {typeCls} {typeCls}-{ui} {inputCls}">{value}</div>',
        {
            disableFormats: true
        }
    ],
    forceSelection: true,

    childEls: [
        'overlayEl'
    ],

    setRawValue: function(value) {
        var me = this;

        // set value in overlay
        if (me.rendered) {
            me.overlayEl.update(value);
        }
        return me.callParent([value]);
    }
});
```

With that, some additional CSS is required:

```
.x-form-text-wrap {
    position: relative;
}

.x-form-field-overlay {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14mm

Comment: wow, thanks so much! How did you get what to do here? Is there some additional info about how to work with tpls in extjs?

Comment: You have source available, that's the best info you can get.

Comment: hmm, thx, found problem here - blur event seems worked but not changed anything

Comment: i guess it's because it need to be working with focus and blur classes! haha

Comment: You asked how to do it, I showed you how, but it doen't mean you can paste it and it will work straightaway.

Comment: I thought that it will inherit all this stuff from his parent, `ComboBox`. I used it as editor for `treecolumn` component

Comment: I've changed template, and now it should behaves a bit better. Instead of replacing input with div, I added div overlay.

Comment: thanks, but, well, got such http://i.imgur.com/wTkpGZZ.png problem here. Tried to make own css class with `display: none !important` and use id inside `<input>` in `fieldSubTpl` but then events (focus/collapse) screwed.

Comment: Finally make it looks okay! Thanks again, mr.Krzysztof!
Just edit the answer pls, like that in css

`.x-form-required-field-overlay {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your editor is `combo`, by default combo (as well as many other components) display HTML as plain text.

[Example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14bd)

I guess as workaround you could overrite `combo` (or any other component), i.e. change component `<input>` element to `<div>`. It will entail overrites of some methods (`setValue()` for example).