# ExtJS cellediting html values using combobox

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, combobox, extjs6

I want to edit treecolumn cell values using basic celleditor with combobox, but values contains html tags. I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016859/extjs-4-render-html-of-a-selected-value-in-a-combobox), but it doesn't work correctly (doesn't complete edit on blur, doesn't expand if `clicksToEdit: 1`).

[Link to example.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h48)

How to fix that?

Comment: One problem seems to be that blur is expected to be fired by the input element, but there is no such input element...

Comment: Yes, so I added it to fieldSubTpl and changed setRawValue method. I added link to fiddle in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `<input>` element into fieldSubTpl with opacity:0 and another div element for show value. [Here a fiddle link.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h4p)